# Sending a state to a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm using a checkbox to add/remove a data to a state(which is an array of strings).

```
<Field
  component={DbCheckbox}
  type="checkbox"
  name={`${contact.name}`}
  color="primary"
  onClick={e => checkboxClick(e, contact)}
/>
```

The onClick do this and set the emails props to the current state

```
const checkboxClick = (e, contact) => {
    e.stopPropagation()

    const resultado = ccEmailSelected.indexOf(contact.email)

    if (resultado === -1) {
        setCcEmailSelected(ccEmailSelected.concat(contact.email))
    } else {
        setCcEmailSelected(ccEmailSelected.filter(i => contact.email !== i))
    }

    props.emails(ccEmailSelected)
}
```

On my parent component, i am using the *emails* prop to receive this array of strings and repopulate on another state

```
emails={(emails) => 
this.setState({ emails }, () => console.log(this.state.emails))}
```

But I am having a problem which I assume is due to the state being async, the first state updates correctly, but my second one, in the parent component, is only updating on a second interaction, causing a reverse result expectation, first I click on the checkbox, the string is added to the first state and not on the second one, then when I click again(unchecking), its removed from the first state and added on the second. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you know that StackOverflow supports adding code snippets that use React?  You'll be able to reproduce your problem for us right here in your question.  That will also greatly help your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: You should have only one source of truth. Remove your local state i  your child component and only use the parent state. Try that, maybe it will help you solve the problem.

Comment: Thats it, i just pass the string directly to the parent state and put the verification there, now it works perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this i just use the state directly on the parent component, my onClick for the checkbox became this

```
  const checkboxClick = (e, contact) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    props.emails(contact.email)
  }
```

And i get these emails on the parent component like this

```
emails={x => {
  const resultado = this.state.emails.indexOf(x)
  if (resultado === -1) {
    this.setState({ emails: [...this.state.emails, x] })
  } else {
    this.state.emails.splice(resultado, 1)
  }
}}
```